# Where to find wordpress query_posts array keys

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to find either in the codex or anywhere, the values one can use when making a custom query. I'm trying to learn it but, i'm not sure what it is i'm looking for.

I've gone to places like [ http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts ] and [ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/ ] that give good examples on how to use it but for example if i do:

```
query_posts( array(
     'category_name' => 'name here', 
     'posts_per_page' => 100  
));
```

I'm aware it may be called something else but in that arrays key/value set above, what i'm looking for is a list that shows all the keys i can use so i can make my own. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is it  you're trying to do? Or are you just looking for a list of the arguments? If so - here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Comment: Yes a list of the things i can use inside that array. Looking at it, kind of like what SIMON below suggested(in the link he provided i mean)

Comment: If you read the link that you provided, it states: ***Note: Parameter details can be found in the Parameter section of the WP_Query class article.

The examples below also work with the WP_Query object. ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use get_posts() instead - and if you look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts you will see a nice big list of all the parameters you can use.

Comment: Hey Simon. thanks 4 the assist. Why should i use get_posts??? is it better in some way?

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts it gives a lot of detail into why you should use it etc...

To summarise query_posts() edits the main query on the site which you really should not be doing. If you want to run a custom query then create a brand new query with get_posts() hence why there is a lot of nice documentation on that with examples. Good luck with it :)